# TinyMVC Model / Plugin how to implement?

Tags: php, mysql

recently i started working with [TinyMVC](http://www.tinymvc.com) wrote a simple menu model and i have few questions for those who are using it .. or used before.
1. For the following code should i keep it as Model or as a Plugin?
2. How should i implement it in the view and use it on every page that is required without breaking the ideea of mvc and without rewriting again and again for each controller?
3. Any improvements to the code?
4. Need the mysql tables ?

[Code Here](http://notey.it/n/bGs):

```
<?php
class Menu_Model extends TinyMVC_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function listMenu()
    {
        return $this->db->query_all("SELECT * FROM menu_links WHERE is_deleted = 0 ORDER BY position");
    }

    public function listCategorys($menuLinkId)
    {
        return $this->db->query_all("SELECT * FROM menu_subcategorys WHERE menuLinkId = ? AND is_deleted = 0 ORDER BY position", array($menuLinkId));
    }

    public function buildMenu()
    {
        $this->listMenu = $this->listMenu();
        foreach($this->listMenu as $this->listMenuKey => $this->listMenuValue)
        {
            $this->listCategorys = $this->listCategorys($this->listMenuValue['menuLinkId']);
            if(!empty($this->listCategorys))
                $this->listMenu[$this->listMenuKey]['child'] = $this->listCategorys;
        }

        return $this->listMenu;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for general feedback and others' opinions, and not a specific problem you've encountered. For those reasons, this might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks colin for your help posted on codereview :-)